# How to parse complex JSON in Swift 4 using Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I need help with parsing JSON from server. Here's the JSON:

```
{
"response": {
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "post",
            "source_id": -17507435,
            "date": 1514538602,
            "post_id": 4105,
            "post_type": "post",
            "text": "Some text here",
            "marked_as_ads": 0,
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "type": "photo",
                    "photo": {
                        "id": 456239655,
                        "album_id": -7,
                        "owner_id": -17507435,
                        "user_id": 100,
                        "photo_75": "https://sun1-3.userapi.com/c840632/v840632924/3b7e7/4YUS7DlaLK8.jpg",
                        "photo_130": "https://sun1-3.userapi.com/c840632/v840632924/3b7e8/Ffpb4ZUlulI.jpg",
                        "photo_604": "https://sun1-3.userapi.com/c840632/v840632924/3b7e9/-pkl6Qdb9hk.jpg",
                        "width": 439,
                        "height": 312,
                        "text": "",
                        "date": 1514538602,
                        "post_id": 4105,
                        "access_key": "6a61a49570efd9c39c"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "post_source": {
                "type": "api"
            },
            "comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "groups_can_post": true,
                "can_post": 1
            },
            "likes": {
                "count": 0,
                "user_likes": 0,
                "can_like": 1,
                "can_publish": 1
            },
            "reposts": {
                "count": 0,
                "user_reposted": 0
            },
            "views": {
                "count": 2
            }
        }
    ],
    "profiles": [],
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 17507435,
            "name": "Literature Museum",
            "screen_name": "samlitmus",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "group",
            "is_admin": 0,
            "is_member": 1,
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/c615722/v615722068/e58c/d5Y8E_5689s.jpg",
            "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c615722/v615722068/e58b/Hm05ga3x2J8.jpg",
            "photo_200": "https://pp.userapi.com/c615722/v615722068/e589/yoG_DDalFII.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 27711883,
            "name": "E:\\music\\melodic hardcore",
            "screen_name": "e_melodic_hc",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "page",
            "is_admin": 0,
            "is_member": 1,
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/c628220/v628220426/47092/xepNnC7pSBw.jpg",
            "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c628220/v628220426/47091/uAokr-c3NQ8.jpg",
            "photo_200": "https://pp.userapi.com/c628220/v628220426/4708f/eNY4vzooz4E.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 81574241,
            "name": "DOS4GW.EXE",
            "screen_name": "dos4gw",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "page",
            "is_admin": 0,
            "is_member": 1,
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/c622118/v622118651/e045/vlhV6QxtoLI.jpg",
            "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c622118/v622118651/e044/P9mVUhXBV58.jpg",
            "photo_200": "https://pp.userapi.com/c622118/v622118651/e043/Soq8oxCMB0I.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 76709587,
            "name": "Prosvet",
            "screen_name": "prosvet_pub",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "page",
            "is_admin": 0,
            "is_member": 0,
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/c630431/v630431500/b24a/GHox8AmDTXU.jpg",
            "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c630431/v630431500/b249/H3mcC-K7htM.jpg",
            "photo_200": "https://pp.userapi.com/c630431/v630431500/b248/9fyvB8gkcwc.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "next_from": "1/4105_1514494800_5"
}
```

}

What I need to get from this JSON are lines: "text", "comments", "likes", "reposts", "attachments".

Inside "attachments" field I want to get "photo_604" line.

Here's my code:

```
class NewsItems: Decodable {
    var text: String?
    var comments: Comments
    var likes: Likes
    var reposts: Reposts
    var attachments: [Attachments]
}

class Comments: Decodable {
    var count: Int?
}

class Likes: Decodable {
    var count: Int?
}

class Reposts: Decodable {
    var count: Int?
}

class Attachments: Decodable {
    var attachments: AttachmentPhoto
}

class AttachmentPhoto: Decodable {
    var photo: WhatIsInsideAttachmentsPhoto
}

class WhatIsInsideAttachmentsPhoto: Decodable {
    var photo: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case photo = "photo_604"
    }
}


class WhatIsIsideResponseNewsFeed: Decodable {
    var items: [NewsItems]
}

public class ResponseNewsFeed: Decodable {
    var response: WhatIsIsideResponseNewsFeed
}
```

But after making the request:

```
Alamofire.request(baseURL+methodName, parameters: parameters).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
        if let result = response.result.value {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let myResponse = try! decoder.decode(ResponseNewsFeed.self, from: result)
            completion(myResponse.response.items)
```

I get an error:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(_UL_PetrovLeonid.NewsItems.(CodingKeys
>   in _FA9A2FC8130449AA328C19ACD9506C2D).attachments,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [_UL_Leonid.ResponseNewsFeed.(CodingKeys in
>   _FA9A2FC8130449AA328C19ACD9506C2D).response, _UL_PetrovLeonid.WhatIsIsideResponseNewsFeed.(CodingKeys in _FA9A2FC8130449AA328C19ACD9506C2D).items, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0))], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
>   attachments (\"attachments\").", underlyingError: nil))

Why is that happening and what do I need to do to solve it? I've been into coding only three months from now, so please forgive me beforehand if my problem seems silly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear

> ... Swift.DecodingError.**keyNotFound** ... **NewsItems.(CodingKeys** in _FA9A2FC8130449AA328C19ACD9506C2D).**attachments** ... **No value associated with key attachments (\"attachments\")**.

- **keyNotFound** is key is missing
- **NewsItems.(CodingKeys ... ).attachments** is the object for key `attachments` in `NewsItems` which is `Attachments`
- **No value associated with key attachments (\"attachments\")** is what is says.

Shortly: There is no key `attachments` in `Attachments` which is true.

Look at your JSON

```
      "attachments": [
            {
                "type": "photo",
                "photo": {
```

The class equivalent is

```
class Attachments: Decodable {
    let type : String
    let photo : AttachmentPhoto
}
```

And `AttachmentPhoto` is supposed to be

```
class AttachmentPhoto: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case photo604 = "photo_604"
        case id
    }

    let id : Int
    let photo604 : String // or even URL
    // etc.
}
```

Actually there is no need to use `class`es, in most cases a `struct` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, vadian, your answer solved the error!

For the newcomer like me it's easy to overlook such things.